# solr query gives different numFound upon refreshing

Tags: solr

I have setup Solr 7.4 cluster with 3 nodes and 3 replicas and 10 collections.

I am facing an issue where refreshing a Solr query may give different results (number of documents returned (**1558** and **1943**)). This issue is seen in all collections.

I think replicas for a given shard are not fully in sync.
[image]

[image]

How can I check and fix this problem?

Comment: Append `shards.info=true` to your query and the response should include information about the `numFound` value per shard. This should tell you which node is the issue.

Comment: .. and a possible suggestion would be to DELETEREPLICA that specific shard, then re-add it again.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks a lot.
I found a problem using `shards.info = true`. Why does this problem occur? How can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Usually it _should_ be caught by the nodes. I'd try to upgrade to the most recent version of Solr first, and check if there's anything in the changelog that could indicate that issues like htis has been fixed. I'm not familiar enough with the low level details of how Solr Cloud determines when and what to replicate to say anything more useful, sorry.

Comment: @MatsLindh I found this solution and I think it can be useful https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solrcloud-recoveries-and-write-tolerance.html#achieved-replication-factor

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much @MatsLindh
I solved this problem by ***min_rf*** parameter .

> Solr supports the optional min_rf parameter on update requests that cause the server to return the achieved replication factor for an update request in the response. For the example scenario described above, if the client application included min_rf >= 1, then Solr would return rf=1 in the Solr response header because the request only succeeded on the leader. The update request will still be accepted as the min_rf parameter only tells Solr that the client application wishes to know what the achieved replication factor was for the update request. In other words, min_rf does not mean Solr will enforce a minimum replication factor as Solr does not support rolling back updates that succeed on a subset of replicas.

> On the client-side, if the achieved replication factor is less than the acceptable level, then the client application can take additional measures to handle the degraded state. For instance, a client application may want to keep a log of which update requests were sent while the state of the collection was degraded and then resend the updates once the problem has been resolved. In short, min_rf is an optional mechanism for a client application to be warned that an update request was accepted while the collection is in a degraded state.

[you can see more details in this link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solrcloud-recoveries-and-write-tolerance.html#achieved-replication-factor)